# arithmetic or geometric sequence in python

Tags: python

Do you know how we can write a code in Python including a function that takes list and find out if it is arithmetic or geometric? I wrote a code but its just Boolean and doesn't say its arithmetic or geometric and also  has an extra output.

```
L=[int(x) for x in input("please enter a list:").split()]

def Arithemetic(L):
  i=1
  if(L[0]+L[i]==L[i+1]):
    return True
  i+=1

def Geometric(L):
  i=1
  if(L[0]*L[i]==L[i+1]):
    return True
  i+=1

def IsArithemeticOrGeometric(L):
  if(Arithemetic(L)):
    print(Arithemetic(L))
  elif(Geometric(L)):
    print(Geometric(L))

print(IsArithemeticOrGeometric(L))
```

Comment: Your implementation of the function `IsArithemeticOrGeometric` returns nothing, but it seems that you planned to return `True` or `False` here. Please correct the source code. Also your functions `Arithemetic` and `Arithemetic` can return True or nothing. It seems that you need to add `return False` at the end of both functions.

Comment: Moreover, your `Arithemetic` and `Geometric` functions only test the case `i=1`: there is no loop to increment `i`.

Comment: I'd do this for the arithmetic sequence: `all((i - j) == (j - k) for i, j, k in zip(l[:-2], l[1:-1], l[2:]))`

Comment: Have you studied loops yet? It is unlikely that looking at the first 3 elements (which is all your code does) is enough. Also -- you only return something *if* a condition is true, but return nothing otherwise.

Comment: A bit of a hint: your `L[0]+L[i]==L[i+1]` is equivalent to the condition `L[i-1]+L[i]==L[i+1]): ` (when `i` is 1). Once the condition is expressed purely in terms of `i` then you can check it in a loop, either returning `False` the first time it fails or returning `True` if you finish the loop with no counterexample found. Make sure you handle the case of lists of length < 2 adequately. There are other ways, but turning what you have into a loop in the most direct way will keep the work your own work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes here, I will try to go over them one by one

## Asking for the list

```
L=[int(x) for x in input("please enter a list:").split()]
```

This will throw a `ValueError` when it gets fed a non-numeric type. This will also round any `float` to `int`

Problem one can be solve by surrounding it with a `while` loop and a `try-catch block`

```
while True:
    try:
        L=[int(x) for x in input("please enter a list:").split()]
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

The problem with the `int` can be easily solved by changing `int(x)` to `float(x)`

When using `float`, beware of [the nature of floating point numbers](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

## Checking for arithmetic and geometric

In your solution, `i` never gets incremented, so this only checks the first two values. Borrowing from @dex-ter's comment you can change this to

```
def is_arithmetic(l):
    return all((i - j) == (j - k) for i, j, k in zip(l[:-2], l[1:-1], l[2:]))
```

For an explanation why on how this works, check the background of [list splicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1562285) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip)

For `is_geometric` you can easily adapt this solution.

This is also an excellent example where `unittests` would've made this error clear

```
assert is_geometric((1,2))
assert is_geometric((1,2, 4))
assert is_geometric((1,2, 4, 8))
assert not is_geometric((1,2, 4, 9))
try:
    is_geometric((1, 2, 'a'))
    raise AssertionError('should throw TypeError')
except TypeError:
    pass
```

## The result

Your result only prints True or False is because that's what you tell your program to do. Your `IsArithemeticOrGeometric()` has no return statement, so it always returns `None`, which does not get printed. , so all the output comes from `print(Arithemetic(L))` or `print(Geometric(L))`

A possible solution here would be something like this:

```
def is_arithmetic_or_geometric(l):
    if is_arithmetic(l):
        return 'arithmetic'
    if is_geometric(l):
        return 'geometric'

print(is_arithmetic_or_geometric(L))
```